# SQL Server 2008 with aggregate function: Conversion failed converting nvarchar to int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I am seeing one issue when running the below query in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT Cast(Substring(c.customername, 12, 4) AS INTEGER)
FROM   customers c
WHERE  ( c. customername LIKE N'____-__-__-____'
         AND Substring(c.customername, 12, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c. customername, 13, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                    '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                    '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c.customername, 14, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c.customername, 15, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND c.uniquekey LIKE '%Plant%'
         AND c.customeruid IN ( 'PriviledgeCustomer' ) )
```

The above query on execution returns the last 4 characters of the object name i.e. customer and works as expected, but as soon as I apply `max` function we get below exception message

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ‘some value’ to data type int.

```
SELECT Max(Cast(Substring(c.customername, 12, 4) AS INTEGER))
FROM   customers c
WHERE  ( c. customername LIKE N'____-__-__-____'
         AND Substring(c.customername, 12, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c. customername, 13, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                    '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                    '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c.customername, 14, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND Substring(c.customername, 15, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                                   '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                                   '8', '9' )
         AND c.uniquekey LIKE '%Plant%'
         AND c.customeruid IN ( 'PriviledgeCustomer' ) )
```

Looks like once `max` function is applied the where condition is not getting executed properly and as a result the query returns all the database records irrespective of the where condition, of which some of the object name are alphanumeric. Any inputs on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: why in where consition u hav individually checked the number character ? by 1 and in the select u  have done substring to 4 ? what values do u get when u do substring to 4 from 12 ?

Comment: can you also provide the definition for Cusotmer name; it is nvarchar with how many characters ?

Comment: that 'some value' will also provide some insight as to what caused the issue. Can u say what tht is ?